BlueDucky not working with Tplink ub500 bt adapter on kali
I am trying to run a CVE implementation, BlueDucky(https://github.com/pentestfunctions/BlueDucky) with my Tplink ub500 bluetooth adapter, but it fails to run.
Some commands I ran to troubleshoot:
python3 BlueDucky.py fails to run with the following error:
{reset}\[{red}!{reset}\] {red}CRITICAL{reset}: No Compatible {blue}Bluetooth devices{reset} are connected.
hcitool scan and bluetoothctl devices have no output. (upon taking a look at the src code the latter command seems to crash the program, but even when I comment out the check it fails to connect to the target android phone)
> hciconfig -a     
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 40:AE:30:15:BF:F0  ACL MTU: 1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:3208 acl:0 sco:0 events:298 errors:0
        TX bytes:39800 acl:0 sco:0 commands:298 errors:0
        Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
        Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
        Name: 'kali'
        Class: 0x7c0000
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
        Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
        HCI Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Revision: 0xdfc6
        LMP Version: 5.1 (0xa)  Subversion: 0xd922
        Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)```

> dmesg | grep -i blue
\[   90.618795\] usb 1-2: Product: TP-Link Bluetooth USB Adapter
\[   91.532917\] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
\[   91.533117\] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
\[   91.533124\] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
\[   91.533137\] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
\[   91.533144\] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
\[   91.533161\] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
\[   91.639281\] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
\[   91.647850\] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
\[   91.647865\] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
\[   91.668912\] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
\[   91.669249\] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
\[   91.677455\] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
\[   91.677530\] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 30210
\[   93.365385\] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
\[   93.365394\] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
\[   93.365402\] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
\[   94.835673\] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0xdfc6d922
\[   95.472171\] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
\[   95.643661\] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
\[   95.643681\] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
\[   95.643695\] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11\`\`\`

NOTE: when I run sudo systemctl stop bluetooth the service doesn't stop. I then try to run sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo modprobe -r bluetooth but the second command fails with modprobe: FATAL: Module bluetooth is in use.
